# Why does each chasidut have its own distinct clothing?

Tags: clothing, chasidut-hasidism

Why does each chasidut have its own distinct clothing?

Google and Wikipedia only list different kinds of clothes, but they don't explain why.

Answer (score 4):

To some degree or other, most Chassidish clothing looks similar (I.e. The bekishe and Kopote look relatively similar, the only difference is the amount of buttons or slits). Different Chassidim come from different parts of Europe where there were different styles. Then as they came to America, each picked up from the local style to some degree or other. Some styles also changed from Europe because of a lack of money of some of the immigrants (The Lubavitcher Rebbe had to reintroduce the Kopote as they were forgotten due to the poverty of the immigrants coming to America) .

Comment: Does he say anywhere why he chose to reintroduce it and not just continue with whatever they had started wearing instead?

Comment: Anybody know why the rebbe switched to a bent down hat as opposed to wearing a Spodik like the previous rebbe did?

Answer (score 4):

Because that's what they've always worn.

Most likely, different number of buttons / slits / color of socks / height of hat / etc, started from some trivial, historical detail, which has long since been forgotten - for example, that's the way the local tailor happened to do it, or a specific *rebbe* just preferred it that way...

And, since *"this is the way we've always done it"*, it has become a big deal, and customary within each sect. And of course, it's forbidden for them to change anything that has always been the custom.

Reminds me of the story of the *rebbe* and the broom in the corner...

Comment: This sort of conventional wisdom is also what I tend to assume, but just based on rumors I've heard. However, to state it thus without any evidence could well be Lashon Hara / Motzi Shem Ra. Can you back this explanation up?

Comment: @Isaac - anecdotally only, so not really evidence. On the other hand, have you heard any claim to the contrary? Even having talked to many of the different types, noone even attempted any explanation other than the equivalent of the broom in the corner... If there is general, passive agreement, I don't think it's LH/MSR. Though perhaps you're right that others would not have stated it so bluntly...

Comment: -1 for the tone of voice ("of course, it's forbidden for them").

Comment: @msh210, I might agree with you, but that is a bad example. *"Issur Chaddash"* is often quoted, as a basis for not changing anything from what our grandfathers did, even issues that are not halachic, or even an actual minhag. Such as the current topic...

Comment: @AviD, perhaps I'm reading some sarcasm where there was none intended?

Comment: @msh210 I'll admit to *some* cynicism, but it is not (I believe)without some basis. Nevermind that, I deserved the downvote...

Comment: The _Chasam Sofer_, I believe, is the one credited with applying the line _chadash asur min hatora_ to isms.

Comment: Btw, this was a legitimate tactic to combat the reform (i don't have a source, but my Rebbe has told me this story). When the reform started, the Chassidim and Litvaks got together to discuss how to combat it. They, obviously did not agree how. The litvaks said to push Torah learning to the front. The Chassidim said that minhagim (even seemingly unneeded) should be pushed to the front. And by wearing different clothing, it will be much harder for a frum yid to go off the derech... Besides for which we have to remember that the yidden were zoche to leave mitzrayim because of how they dressed.

Comment: I will try to get the names of the two gedolim (the Litvishe Gadol and Chassidishe Rebbe) that had that meeting.

Comment: @Mennyg that sentiment would hold more water if it wasn't specifically the same clothes that everyone else wore at the time (e.g. Polish noblemen). As generations passed, and the original cause of these clothes was no longer relevant (e.g. they moved to other countries, these were no longer popular even in Poland, etc), then your explanation makes sense - but at that point it is no longer the original cause...

Comment: I'm not %100 sure as i heard the story about 11 years ago, but it could be that they made sure to keep wearing whatever they were already wearing. They didnt go backwards. But they would not change with the styles of Italy. I know for sure that the kapote was created by a Rov in Warsaw R' Yakkov Gezundheit after there was a decree forbidding the Bekishe (before that, ALL of Klal Yisroel wore bekishes, even the litvaks. Even though the goyishe world was going with short jackets). This happened in the early 1900s. The Chiddushei Harim of Gur, argued that if they change, they'll lose the fact....

Comment: That they have been wearing te same for 100s of years and eventually we'll lose everything. He fought for the bekishe. Today, we see that the kapote is almost entirely lost. Btw, the kapote actually was created by taking a tailcoat and building it to the front (a compromise that was made with the governor of Warsaw) if you look at the seems onone, it'll make sense

Comment: `started from some trivial, historical detail` It's my sense that this is true for the most part, but that some idiosyncratic aspects of the Chasidic garb of various groups were originally chosen for deliberate, religious reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to do with chassidus but traditions over years from what country and cities their families cam from.

Much of various Jewish clothing is loosely based on what the Jews wore in Babylonia which included a long garment and a round hat.

Of course over time styles have changed and evolved to what they are today.

As far as any connection to chassidim (not chassidus) many simple wear what their Rebbe wears but this is not necessarily always the case as personal preference can vary from individuals as well as personal and family customs.

Answer (score -3):

Because they follow the first Admurim. In my personal think this its a great thing. This can help them in avoidas hashem. For instance, the long white socks or the Chasidishe  shirts are all old clothes which we still keep from the first leaders of the Chassidut. That is why every Chassidic group has its particular and different clothes.

Comment: Who are the old rabbis? What do they have to do with every hassid wearing different things?

Comment: Please fix your spelling to be understandable and explain what you mean.