# Chasidic Clothing

Tags: clothing, chasidut-hasidism

I am very interested to know a bit about the differences of clothing between the chasidic dinasties. I saw there are some differences in their hats and socks, for example. Does anyone here know a bit more about it?

Comment: Cf https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9446/170

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Levi and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Note in particular what questions are in scope - yours might get closed for not being about Judaism but rather about Jewish lifestyle which is not in scope. Hopefully this won't deter you from staying to learn with us.

Comment: Hi! I am sorry. I will have a look on your guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

For most groups the differences  amount to which region in Europe they came from.

IOW  some groups wear  clothes that are thought of today as being unique to that group   but if you would look at pre  holocaust pictures of decimated no longer existing Hasidic  groups coming from the same region you will see that they dressed the same  way.

A  few surviving Hasidic groups did not have such a distinct dress code in Europe at all.  After the holocaust when  mode of dress became a more important  factor in Hasidic identity they took  on the dress of the other Hasidic dynasties that had been in their region before WWII